# Read POST request body PDF content and create new PDF File

Tags: java, pdf, post, attachment

I want to create a REST POST endpoint for receiving a PDF file and converting it into a byte array.

The content of the request.getBody() looks like this. Made the call by Postman and attached file via binary option.

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by encoding the message in Base64 before sending it in the body of the message.